# $\int_{0}^1\,\frac{1}{n+{(-1)}^n}\,dn $

Tags: integration

My questions:

> How to solve the integral J:
>   $$
> J=\int_{0}^1\,\frac{1}{n+{(-1)}^n}\,dn 
> $$

My try:

> I know the value of integral I is ${\frac {2\,i}{\pi }}$:
>    $$ I=\int_{0}^1\,{(-1)}^n\,dn $$

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: i believe your integral can not expressed by the known elementary mathematical functions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is a theorem of Liouville, reproven later with purely algebraic methods, that for rational functions $f$ and $g$, $g$ nonconstant, the antiderivative

$$\int [f(x)\exp(g(x))] \, \mathrm dx$$

can be expressed in terms of elementary functions if and only if there exists some rational function $h$ such that it is a solution to the differential equation:
$$f = h' + hg$$ I do not know how to apply Liouville theorem for this integral.

Comment: It's perhaps not the best idea to call the integration variable $n$. That aside, $J$ is a divergent integral. $$\frac{1}{z + e^{(2k+1)\pi i z}}$$ has a simple pole at $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's good idea, i work on it, thanks.

Comment: What's $\left(\,-1\,\right)^{n}$ branch-cut ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin there is a command in Maple that obtains the branch cut and point of function, but the first variable of command in Maple must be a name of function like *arcsin* or *exp*. I dont know how to define it for Maple.

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Maple. I understand your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is too long for a comment.*

I suppose that there are some problems for an upper bound equal to $1$.

Let us consider the series expansion of the integrand.

Built around $x=0$
$$\frac{1}{x+{(-1)}^x}=1-(1+i \pi ) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$
but built around $n=1$
$$\frac{1}{x+{(-1)}^x}=\frac{1}{(1-i \pi ) (x-1)}+\frac{\pi ^2}{2 (\pi +i)^2}-\frac{i \pi ^3\left(\pi -2 i \right) (x-1)}{12 (\pi +i)^3}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

**Edit**

Just for illustration purposes, using numerical integration for 
$$I_k=\int_0^{1-10^{-k}} \frac{dx}{x+{(-1)}^x}$$ The results, given in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \Re(I_k) & \Im(I_k) \\
 1 & +0.387613870 & -0.797797769 \\
 2 & +0.210518936 & -1.486801986 \\
 3 & +0.002029374 & -2.154668599 \\
 4 & -0.209474141 & -2.820410549 \\
 5 & -0.421277862 & -3.485939933 \\
 6 & -0.633111987 & -4.151449301 \\
 7 & -0.844948324 & -4.816954064 \\
 8 & -1.056785359 & -5.482459867 \\
 9 & -1.268622453 & -6.147965736 \\
 10 & -1.480459725 & -6.813472155 \\
 11 & -1.692296547 & -7.478977159 \\
 12 & -1.904133612 & -8.144482925 \\
 13 & -2.115970676 & -8.809988692 \\
 14 & -2.327807742 & -9.475494460 \\
 15 & -2.539644807 & -10.14100023 \\
 16 & -2.751481861 & -10.80650596 \\
 17 & -2.963318900 & -11.47201165 \\
 18 & -3.175155911 & -12.13751725 \\
 19 & -3.386993058 & -12.80302327 \\
 20 & -3.598830695 & -13.46853083
\end{array}
\right)$$ reveal almost linear dependencies of both parts to $k$ (for both cases, $R^2 > 0.9999$).

I also computed $$J_k=\int_k^{k+1} \frac{dx}{x+{(-1)}^x}$$ 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \Re(J_k) & \Im(J_k) \\
 2 & 0.3804654786 & -0.09766095828 \\
 3 & 0.2982340414 & +0.05791242965 \\
 4 & 0.2187482594 & -0.03102019469 \\
 5 & 0.1848637288 & +0.02194294166 \\
 6 & 0.1526833198 & -0.01497093693 \\
 7 & 0.1345140836 & +0.01157107283 \\
 8 & 0.1171253079 & -0.00877804731 \\
 9 & 0.1058399060 & +0.00715137188 \\
 10 & 0.0949608499 & -0.00576000060 \\
 11 & 0.0872804187 & +0.00485888165 \\
 12 & 0.0798355256 & -0.00406722502 \\
 13 & 0.0742738422 & +0.00351679661 \\
 14 & 0.0688600856 & -0.00302397107 \\
 15 & 0.0646479283 & +0.00266342347 \\
 16 & 0.0605344815 & -0.00233600956 \\
 17 & 0.0572343474 & +0.00208711753 \\
 18 & 0.0540032574 & -0.00185861089 \\
 19 & 0.0513481342 & +0.00167963063 \\
 20 & 0.0487431481 & -0.00151387073
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: If is it possible, please explain more, I can't get it. Thanks

Comment: As Daniel Fischer commented, the second expansion shows the pole at $n=1$. What would happen if you integrate between $0.9999$ and $1$ ?

Comment: It,s infinity but my aim for asking this question was how to show that $\int\,\frac{1}{n+{(-1)}^n}\,dn$ is not integrable.  Perhaps, it was better that i asked how to solve $\int_a^b\,\frac{1}{n+{(-1)}^n}\,dn$ where $a,b>1$. Thanks for comment.

Comment: This is then a different story, for sure. I don't have much hope but I shall try to see what I can do tomorrow morning (it is 9:00pm here). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your try. Have a good night.

Comment: @Amin235. I added some numerical results. To me, the most interesting are related to $I_k$ which clearly show the "explosion" when approaching the upper bound of $1$. Have fun ! Cheers.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate for your useful edition.